# Function $f$ subordinate to function $g$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, hypergeometric-function, schwartz-space

I'm trying to study a research paper, during that i come across this word **Subordinate**, i searched this a lot on google but didn't get any satisfactory answer. I understand the definition they gave in this paper, but the problem is what they want to convey and what is the purpose of this, how will this help. Please help me with this

**Here i a screenshot**

[image]

**Thankyou**

Comment: In complex analysis subordination is a sort of "holomoprhic" replacement for inequalities $f \le g$ that make sense only for real functions, as holomoprhic functions are never taking only real vues unless constant; many times is used to solve extremal problems (eg any holomorphic function from the unit disc to the right half plane - ie with positive real part and taking $0$ to $1$ - is subordinated to $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ so it is "less" than that in some sense that involves both argument and absolute value)

Comment: Thank you @Conrad for the help, but i'm not getting why they using Schwarzian function $\omega (z)$ in definition?

Comment: because it satisfies $|\omega(z)| \le |z|$ so this means that if $f=g \circ \omega$ then the image under $f$ of the disc of radius $r$ is included in the image of same disc under $g$ hence not only $f(\mathbb U) \subset g(\mathbb U)$ but all $f(\mathbb U_r) \subset g(\mathbb U_r), 0 < r \le 1$; if $g$ is univalent then only the conditions $f(\mathbb U) \subset g(\mathbb U), f(0)=g(0)$ are enough to define subordination as one takes $\omega = g^{-1} \circ f$ but if one wants to define subordination without requiring that condition you need the more general defintion

Comment: Thankyou @Conrad your two comments has cleared my bunch of doubts, one thing more ,so as per your first comment if lets say $f$ subordinate $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ in open disk $|z|<1$ then does it means $|f(a)| < |\frac{1+a}{1-a}|$ ? where $a \in |z|<1$

Comment: No, it means $|f(a)| \le  \frac{1+|a|}{1-|a|}$; for example $f(z)=\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ is obviously subordinated to $g(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ but $f(-1/2)=3, g(-1/2)=1/3$ so taking $f_{1}(z)=f(rz)$ for some $r<1$ close to $1$ we still have $|f_1(1/2)| >g(1/2)$ and now we have a "proper" subordination; the individual values of $f,g$ may not be directly related, what is related are the images of discs

Comment: More generally since obviously $g(\alpha z)$ is subordinated to $g$ for any $|\alpha|=1$ hence $g(\alpha rz)$ is "properly" subordinated to $g$ for any $r<1$, you can rotate any $a$ and find a function $f$ subordinated to $g$ for which $f(a)$ is as close to any fixed $g(b)$ where $|a| =|b|$ so you can find a subordinated function to $g$ that at a given point on a circle is almost as big as the maximum of $g$ on that circle, so you cannot do better than the above

Comment: Can you please recommend me any book which have this topic with some deep explanation?

Comment: both Duren and Pommerenke's treatises on Univalent functions discuss this nicely, while there is a whole book by Miller and Mocanu (Differential Subordination) that applies the notion of subordination to get various classical and new results